# Firebase AppCheck can't see metrics and enforce option

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-app-check

To practice I've built an app with Flutter and Realtime Database. Right now is intended for personal use only, so there's no authentication feature and I have no intention to publish it to the store. I've also implemented Firebase App Check with Play Integrity provider and it is correctly registered
[image]

The app works fine but, aside from the fact that I continue to receive emails from Firebase about security rules warning, I've noticed I'm missing the "enforce" option, so I'm not sure App Check is in fact working.
In the app check console, I expect to see this:
[image]

While my App Check section looks like this, without metrics and the "enforce" option:
[image]

Do the metrics and the "enforce" options work only with published apps or am I missing something?

Secondly, is there a way to fix the security rules (read: true write: true right now) without implementing firebase authentication?